# How to render React components based on the DOM coordinates of other components?

Tags: reactjs, svg, tree

I am using React to render a tree. The nodes are plain HTML, the edges are inline SVG within each HTML node.

> What is the recommended way to render components (nodes), get their DOM coordinates, build new components based on those coordinates (edges) and render them?

Any action that changes the coordinates of any node (eg: renaming a node or adding new nodes) should trigger the calculation of *all* the edges, as any node that moves will also move the surrounding nodes.

I have 4 main components:

- `HierarchyChart`, contains the recursive function to build the tree branches. It creates a `Branch` for each `Node`.
- `Branch` is a component with a parent `Node`, and children `Node` if they exist.
- `Node`
- `Edge`

[This is the kind of tree I'm trying to paint.](https://codepen.io/gregoryforel/pen/ppGzyR) It can give you a clue of the resulting HTML built by React.

So far, I used `componentDidMount` in `HierarchyChart` to get the DOM coordinates of all the nodes but this only works one time. So I got some success, but the moment I add mode nodes, it doesn't paint all the edges.

I then tried to use `componentDidUpdate`, but realised that this would  trigger an infinite loop.

Any hint whether or not I'm using the right strategy is highly appreciated.

Comment: Using `componentDidUpdate` is a great solution. You just need to make sure `prevState !== this.state` before doing making any changes. This should prevent the infinite loop.

Comment: What's your address, so I can send 10 packs of beers?? :) I used prevProps !== this.props in my particular case, but you got me on the right path. If you write an answer, I'll validate as such. Thanks a mil

Comment: Haha it's the thought that counts man, thanks! Glad you got it working.